# two-dimensional array Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a two-dimension array in my django app which I need to pass to html template.

How I can make HTML handle two-dimensional array?

```
 {% block content %}

  <h2>Survey</h2>
      <form>

    {% for q in question %}   
          <p>{{q[0]}}</p>
          <p>{{q[1]}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I got error:

```
    Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'q[0]'
```

Answer (score 12):

```
{% block content %}

  <h2>Survey</h2>
      <form>

    {% for q in question %}   
          <p>{{q.0}}</p>
          <p>{{q.1}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django just doesn't have a pre-setup way for passing multi-dimensional arrays to templates.

The best work-around is to separate the columns out manually like so... ("i" corresponds to each row in final output)

```
data = {}    
for i, question_answer in enumerate(question_answer_pairs):
    data[i]= {
        'question':question_answer.question,
        'answer':question_answer.answer
    }
return render(request, 'survey.html', data)
```

Then in your template

```
{% block content %}

  <h2>Survey</h2>
      <form>

    {% for key,value in data.items %}   
          <p>{{value.question}}</p>
          <p>{{value.answer}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </form>

{% endblock %}
```